# How to calc 4×4 matrix that covert a set of point from one 3D coordinate to another 3D coordinate

Tags: 3d

Now $n$ points($p_1 ,\ldots, p_n$) are given in a cartesian $3D$ coordinate system: $L_1$. Actually, $L_1$ is a local coordinate system of a $3D$ model.

And $n$ points($P_1,\ldots ,P_n$) are given in the other cartesian $3D$ coordinate system: $L_2$.$ L_2$ is the Earth-centered, Earth-fixed coordinate system: ECEF.

$Pi$ represents the converted point of $p_i$ from $L_1$ to $L_2$.

Now I want to find the matrix$4$ that convert points in $L_1$ to $L_2$ with the minimum error. Is this possible mathematically? Any idea or suggestion would be thankful.

**Context.**

I have a 3d model provided by an artist.
I want to render it on the 3D earth.
But we have not correct georeferencing information about 3d model.
So we want to make users georeference it in our application.

**Our application use case.**

He selects $p_1$ on the 3d model's local 3D cartesian coordinate system.
Then he selects $P_1$ on the earth that corresponds to $p_1$.
And then he $p_2$ on the local then $P_2$ on the earth.
...
In this way, he provides two sets of points.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Does "matrix4" means a $4 \times 4$ matrix ?

Comment: It sounds like you're interested in homogeneous coordinates. See, eg https://math.stackexchange.com/q/336/207316

Comment: No answer to my question ?

Comment: yes. matrix4" means a 4×4 matrix